# Prestashop product image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

How would you get a product image using javascript in Prestashop? I already know in tpl and php you can use this

```
$imagePath = Link::getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $product['id_product'], 'home_default'); 

{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_product, 'home_default')}`
```

Is this possible to do this in javascript?

Comment: Huh? Get the image how? Its URL? Its data? Its ID? Sorry, you need to be a lot more specific. You might also try and explain what you've already tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry had to write it quickly, but we already have the productID. We pull that the same way prestashop pulls it using the blockcart module. When the add to cart button is pressed the javascript pulls the id off the of the rel tag example "ajax_id_product_14" We then have product_id 14. Our only problem is how to use that ID within the javascript to get the product's image. Hope that is a little clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use : $('img#ID-of-your-img').attr('src')
this will return you the link to the image ;) .

Answer (score 0):

If you use your javascript file in the same tpl than you can write this.

```
{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_product, 'home_default')}
```

If you want to get product image from external file than you can find the product image by using the **product_image class**
like.

```
.product_image img
```

and it will help you to get the images of product.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question thats why i entered this 'stack'

Challenge: Wanted image with different sizes then default product.image size in #layer_cart

Solution:
Made an image with name popup_default in the BO of prestashop.

In /themes/theme_name/modules/blockcart/blockcart-json.tpl added the following at line 36

```
"image_popup": {$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'popup_default')|json_encode},
```

Then in /themes/theme_name/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js
made the following change at line 737

```
$('.layer_cart_img').html('<img class="layer_cart_img img-responsive" src="' + product.image + '" alt="' + product.name + '" title="' + product.name + '" />');
```

into

```
$('.layer_cart_img').html('<img class="layer_cart_img img-responsive" src="' + product.image_popup + '" alt="' + product.name + '" title="' + product.name + '" />');
```

Now i use an image with 'popup' sizes